# Erro de sintaxe com uso de ponteiro

Tags: c++, ponteiro

```
int main() {
    char const* path = "/bla/bla";
    struct zip *teste;
    int *errorp;
    &teste   = *zip_open(path, ZIP_CREATE, errorp);
    return 0;
}
```

Ele retorna esse erro:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:11:50: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
>      &teste   = *zip_open(path, ZIP_CREATE, errorp);
> ```

Acho que é porque eu não estou atribuindo nada a `errorp` mas o ela precisa guardar exatamente? quando eu atribuo um número a ela da erro de conversão.

Eu estou seguindo [essa documentação](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_open.html).

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Tenho duas coisas pra te dizer: primeiro está programando em C e não C++, e isto é preocupante, está cometendo um erro básico, então não seria o caso de aprender os mecanismos da linguagem antes de aprender fazer algo mais complexo?

Assim funciona:

```
int main() {
    char const* path = "/bla/bla";
    int *errorp;
    struct zip *teste = zip_open(path, ZIP_CREATE, errorp);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Pointer/CorrectSyntax.cpp).

A sintaxe da chamada da função está completamente errada, nem imagino porque colocou o `&` e `*`, nela.

Tem pelo menos outro problema visível neste código que vai melar a execução (não aloca memória para `errorp`), e algo me diz que nem é assim que usa esta biblioteca, então solucionar este problema vai adiantar pouco. O problema descrito está solucionado.

Comment: Eu fiz assim porque os exemplos que eu encontrei na internet usavam esse código, eu prefiro aprender fazendo coisas mais complexas, assim o aprendizado não fica chato, e na minha pergunta eu deixo a dúvida quanto a variável errorp, do jeito que você fez, ele retorna um erro dizendo que precisa de uma referencia pra "zip_open", por isso usei o "&", agora se você não sabe o funcionamento dessa biblioteca, de que forma sua resposta pode contribuir pra pergunta?

Comment: Não usam assim porque esta sintaxe não existe e copiar exemplo da internet sem entender o que está acontecendo ali não é programar ou aprender a programar. Se acha aprender programar do jeito correto chato então minha sugestão é procurar uma atividade que lhe agrade mais. Sinto te dizer isto, mas você não está aprendendo programar, está apenas tentando fazer um código compilar e eventualmente executar algo. Eu respondi o que perguntou que é um erro de sintaxe, você não perguntou como usar a biblioteca.

Comment: Amigo, cada um tem seu modo de aprendizado, não preciso de outra atividade, meu sonho é ser programador e vou conseguir independente do que você ache, Obrigado por nada.

Comment: Boa sorte, vai precisar.

Comment: @Maniero, eu gostei da sua resposta. Ela, de fato, resolve parcialmente o problema apresentado na pergunta. Porém, infelizmente, considero equivocada a sua defesa de que exista uma maneira correta de se aprender uma linguagem de programação, bem como também considero inadequada a sua sugestão de que as pessoas que não se adaptam a essa maneira correta deveriam procurar algo que lhes agrade mais.

Comment: @v.Santos ok. Eu também não concordo com um negativo em resposta que é dita como certa, então negativou a resposta pelo comentário. Não parece coerente. Também não parece coerente dizer que deve ter outras formas diferentes de fazer algo, mas considerou que só a sua forma é a certa e como a minha forma de pensar é errada eu merecia uma punição. Também não é coerente porque não disse que não existe outras formas de aprender, eu disse que esta forma é errada, faz 35 anos que faço isso e vi muita gente tentando aprender de várias formas, esse teve 0 pessoas com sucesso em todo esse tempo.

Comment: Porém eu acho que todo mundo tem o direito de aprender do jeito que quiser, em nenhum momento eu proíbo alguém de fazer do jeito que eu sei que não funciona, até porque quem vai sofrer todas consequências ruins da decisão ruim é ela mesma, então ela pode fazer, eu só tento mostrar que tem jeito melhor, tento ajudar, ninguém é obrigado a aceitar a ajuda e ode quebrar a cara por conta própria, só espero que depois não diga que eu não avisei. Também não faz sentido dizer sobre o que é inadequado quando eu sequer falei o que foi afirmado aí.

Comment: O que eu disse é que se achar chato aprender programar é melhor desistir da profissão porque ela é cheia de coisas chatas o tempo todo. Não quero iludir alguém, não quero fazer pessoas que querem coisas divertidas acharem que programação é assim. Até é em algum momento, mas é cheio de coisa chata também e é bom se acostumar com isso. O texto é curto demais pra fazer essa inferência que fez. Mas as pessoas podem ser incoerentes, mesmo só discordando sem apresentar argumentos, ainda que de fato nem estão no escopo aqui.

Comment: "Eu quero aprender, mas só com coisa que eu concordo" - isso é suicídio intelectual em qualquer área, alem de um contrasenso por natureza (aproveite quem quiser).

Comment: Diria que o comentário do Maneiro deveria valer até para outros supostos profissionais, como médicos, advogados, "servidores", etc. Muita coisa acaba mal feita porque a pessoa esta em uma área unicamente pelos supostos lucros que irá obter e não pelo interesse real, não falo de paixão por aquilo, mas sim de entender, aprender e executar tecnicamente e se aperfeiçoar, tem muita gente que faz uns cursos imbecis (imbecis mesmo) e acreditam estar se aperfeiçoando, quando na verdade só estão enchendo linguiça. Pessoalmente creio ser valido dizer que certas formas de fazer levam a problemas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o problema é que ele nem sabe a metodologia que eu uso para estudo e já vai chutando uma coisa que ele nem sabe, ele pode ter 400 anos de experiência, ele não é Deus, um método correto pra estudar e aprender não existe, e o jeito que eu tenho estudado até agora me tem ajudado muito.

Comment: Caro @zaque entendo seu aborrecimento, tento me imaginar fora daqui para compreender, claro que o sentimento é apenas seu, mas eu já estive em lugar parecido, realmente pensando assim, eu já sofri muito para estudar, em uma época que a melhor internet que tinhamos era 2mb (10mb só rico) e 3G ainda parecia um sonho (mal tinhamos 2G), hoje temos as coisas mais fáceis, creio que é o seu cenário atual e realmente acho que o Maniero tem muita experiencia e sustança no que diz, e as palavras podem até soar mal a primeira vista, mas foi procurando pessoas como ele que consegui trilhar o meu [...]

Comment: [...] caminho o caminho das pedras pode chegar lá, mas causará traumas demais, se eu fosse você colocaria em uma balança imaginaria o que vale a pena, ouvir alguém que tem experiencia, mesmo que as vezes parecer (eu disse que parece, não significa que ele é) ou bater com a cabeça em diversos lugares e problemas? A escolha é sua, claro, mas  já lhe adianto, pessoas como o Maneiro, Bacco, Anderson e Jefferson (logo irá conhecer os 2 ultimos) são pessoas incriveis que gastam o pouco tempo que tem compartilhando conhecimento testado, lógico e muitas vezes apresentando referencias/fontes. [...]

Comment: [...] Devo dizer que o Maniero dá palestras sobre tecnologia e realmente você poderia refletir se de fato ele esta sendo duro contigo, mas para lhe fortalecer e não para lhe oprimir.

Comment: @zaque você informou sua metodologia: `Eu fiz assim porque os exemplos que eu encontrei na internet usavam esse código, eu prefiro aprender fazendo coisas mais complexas`. Existe método correto para aprender, tem milhares de pessoas que se dedicam a entender isso e obter o melhor resultado e isto está documentado, inclusive muitos desses estudos são especificamente para a área da computação, que já foi classificadas como uma das mais difíceis de aprender (de verdade). E algumas pessoas participaram do aprendizado de milhares de pessoas e viu os resultados.

Comment: Mas infelizmente algumas pessoas acham que nasceram sabendo e que com seu conhecimento nato vão chegar a algum lugar e podem ignorar todo o conhecimento criado pelas pessoas que vieram antes. Também tem estudos sobre isto, mas como quase ninguém entende disto foi criado um termo popular, são chamadas de floquinho de neve.

Comment: A parte trágica é que as pessoas assim não conseguem sair do círculo vicioso que entraram porque elas sempre acham que os outros que possuem experiência estão erradas e elas que estão começando agora é que sabem o que é certo, e passam a vida toda iludidas e culpando os outros por seus fracassos. Eu sempre vou fazer minha parte para evitar isso, mesmo que me custe arrumar alguns desafetos, faz parte. Me omitir eu não farei. Afinal foi por omissão de uma geração de pais que surgiram todos esses problemas. Me desculpe se te incomoda, só quis ajudar.